# Composer will not work with current settings

Tags: php, mongodb, composer-php, php-extension

The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:

`C:\xampp\php\php.exe`

The `php.ini` used by your command-line PHP is: `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`

Program Output:

> Warning: PHP Startup: mongo: Unable to initialize module
>   Module compiled with module API=20121212
>   PHP compiled with module API=20131226
>   These options need to match in Unknown on line 0

**Update**

**Composer can't find mongodb extension in php**

```
C:\wamp\www\phpmongodb>composer require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.0.0"
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: You replaced your original question with a new one. Don't do that! I've reverted your edit, so that the original question is shown and added your new content as an update.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: PHP Startup: **mongo**: Unable to initialize module
>   Module compiled with module API=20121212
>   PHP compiled with module API=20131226
>   These options need to match in Unknown on line 0

**Problem**

This is a PHP Extension installation issue.

The error means, that the PHP Extension **mongo** doesn't fit your PHP version.
It's incompatible.

**Solution**

- The solution is to check your PHP version with `php -v` and then install the matching "mongo" extension.

  PHP Extension **Mongo** https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo + http://php.net/mongo/

  > **Reminder:** The PHP extension Mongo is deprecated. The replacement is MongoDB https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb + http://php.net/mongodb/
- Another simple solution is to delete the `php_mongo.dll` from the extension folder and remove it from `php.ini` to allow a proper PHP start.

After that, Composer and all other PHP CLI applications should work normally.

**Answer for the updated question**

`the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system`

Now, mongodb is missing:

1. Download
2. drop php_mongodb.dll into the extension folder
3. edit your php.ini to include the extension.